# Regex for string enclosed in <*>, C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get all strings enclosed in <*> by using following Regex:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\<(?<name>\S+)\>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string name = e.Match.Groups["name"].Value;
```

But in some cases where I have text like :

```
<Vendors><Vtitle/>  <VSurname/></Vendors>
```

It's returning two strings instead of four, i.e. above Regex outputs

```
<Vendors><Vtitle/> //as one string and 
<VSurname/></Vendors> //as second string
```

Where as I am expecting four strings:

```
<Vendors>
<Vtitle/>
<VSurname/>
</Vendors>
```

Could you please guide me what change I need to make to my Regex.

I tried adding '\b' to specify word boundry

```
new Regex(@"\b\<(?<name>\S+)\>\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

, but that didn't help.

Comment: Is there any good reason not to use an xml parser here?

Comment: Agreed with Marc; use an XML parser. Unless you want to build one.

Comment: Are you parsing an XML document or do you have angle bracket tags inside a mostly plain text document? XML parsers are particular about having well formatted XML documents. They wouldn't work for finding a few angle bracket tags sprinkled throughout a text document.

Comment: OK, I just saw OP's comment on Andrew's answer. These tags happen to look like XML, but this isn't about parsing XML. This is about finding angle bracket delimited text within a mostly plain text document.

Comment: Here is the best ever answer on your question. It have 2302 votes up. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 10):

You'll get most of what what you want by using the regex `/<([^>]*)>/`. (No need to escape the angle brackets' as angle brackets aren't special characters in most regex engines, including the .NET engine.) The regex I provided will also capture trailing whitespace and any attributes on the tag--parsing those things reliably is way, way beyond the scope of a reasonable regex.

However, be aware that if you're trying to parse XML/HTML with a regex, [that way lies madness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: By answering this question, however, the OP might use this regex (and more regexes) instead of the better methods. Then 2-3 years down the road someone's going to have to maintain it.

Answer (score 6):

Regexes are the wrong tool for parsing XML. Try using the `System.Xml.Linq` (`XElement`) API.

Comment: See Dennis Palmer's comment on the original question.  This isn't XML.

Answer (score 4):

Your regex is using \S+ as the wildcard.  In english, this is "a series of one or more characters, none of which is non-whitespace".  In other words, when the regex `<(?<name>\S+)>` is applied to this string:  '`, the regex will match the entire string.  angle brackets are non-whitespace.

I think what you want is "a series of one or more characters, none of which is an angle bracket".

The regex for that is `<(?<name>[^>]+)>`  .

Ahhh, regular expressions.  The language designed to look like cartoon swearing.

Comment: +2 if I could for cartoon swearing.